# Is "I wanted to have written something more round" correct? Or do I have to use "rounder"? Or is only well-rounded is acceptable?

Tags: adjectives, comparatives

Is "I wanted to have written something more round" correct? Or do I have to use "rounder"?

I think that I hear more people saying "This should be more round", than "This should be rounder". When round means to be in a good shape, decent quality.

Please help me find out which is the appropriate way to say this.

EDIT: It has been suggested that "well-rounded" is the appropriate expression. But also mentioned that "Your writing should be better rounded." could also be appropriate.

Then, I ask: should I say:
1 - "I wanted to have written something more well-rounded"
or
2 - "I wanted to have written something better rounded"?

EDIT 2:
These links came up in a research about these words, but they do not explain usage well enough. Hence, my question. Thank you.

- https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/well-rounded
- https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/well-rounded
- https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/more%20rounded

Comment: Hi, what have you found in your research?  Please include your findings; even dictionary entries are good sources.

Comment: 'more round' and 'rounder' (both acceptable syntactically) mean 'closer to a round shape' (ie not metaphorical). 'Well-rounded' is not literal at all. For the comparative, use 'more well-rounded'. An alternative is 'more filled out'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is "I wanted to have written something more round" correct?

No.

> Or do I have to use "rounder"?

No that is wrong too.

> I think that I hear more people saying "This should be more round", than "This should be rounder". When round means to be in a good shape, decent quality.

You think wrongly, or the people are not native speakers or speak substandard English or a dialect.

> "This should be rounder". When round means to be in a good shape, decent quality.

I doubt this. You can use "rounder" but it is mainly an attributive adjective often with a modifying adverb: it is rarely a predicative adjective.

Here are some examples of "rounded":

> 1850   Blackwood's Edind. Mag. Apr. 442/2   *A carefully rounded phrase intended for the ear of royalty.*
>
> 1986   N.Y. Times (Nexis) 19 Jan. g17/1   *Most of the characters speak in rounded periods, often with a touch of malicious wit.*
>
> 2001   G. Indiana Depraved Indifference (2003) 122   *The things he'd practiced telling her in nice rounded sentences full of vocabulary reached her as the oppressive gibberish of an implacable child.*

> Please help me find out which is the appropriate way to say this.

The easiest way is a rewrite:

"I wanted to have written something more well-rounded"

The OED entry in this context is:

> **well-rounded** (adj)
>
> **2. Of a sentence, phrase, etc.: very neatly finished; elegantly expressed.**
>
> 1764   Crit. Rev. Feb. 108   *Those amongst our readers who look only for smooth and well-rounded periods..will be greatly disappointed.*
>
> 1946   Amer. Hist. Rev. 51 349   *In a country attuned to the
> well-rounded phrase, that was Rui's great advantage: he was a born orator.*
>
> 2005   R. P. Irvine J. Austen 73   *This paragraph consists of a series of clauses and phrases separated by dashes and semi-colons instead of Austen's more usual well-rounded sentences.*

**Well-rounded** is more emphatic and, I suspect, commoner than rounded.

The idea behind "rounded" is that the object has had the roughness taken from it and is now smooth and round like a billiard/pool ball.

Answer (score 1):

**None of those phrases make sense to me**

I'm a native of the U.S. living in Montana.

None of your example sentences make sense to me. Or, more accurately, I wouldn't say anything using any of those phrases. But it's possible you're trying to use a form of "[well-rounded](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/well-rounded)."

> 1. adjective
>
> You describe someone as well-rounded when you are expressing approval of them because they have a personality which is fully developed in all aspects.
>
> 2. adjective
>
> If you describe something that is made up of several parts as well-rounded, you mean that the way that the different parts are put together is good, because there is not too much or too little of any one part.
>
> **well-rounded in American English**
>
> (ˈwɛlˈraʊndɪd ) adjective
>
> 1. well-planned for proper balance, "a well-rounded education"
> 2. showing interest or ability in many fields or showing many facets of personality, "a well-rounded character"
> 3. fully developed; shapely, "a well-rounded figure"
>
> *Webster’s New World College Dictionary, 4th Edition. Copyright © 2010 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt. All rights reserved.*
>
> **well-rounded in American English**
>
> (ˈwelˈraundɪd) adjective
>
> 1. having desirably varied abilities or attainments
> 2. desirably varied, "a well-rounded curriculum"
> 3. fully developed; well-balanced
>
> *Most material © 2005, 1997, 1991 by Penguin Random House LLC. Modified entries © 2019 by Penguin Random House LLC and HarperCollins Publishers Ltd*
>
> **well-rounded in British English**
>
> adjective (well rounded when postpositive)
>
> 1. rounded in shape or well developed, "a well-rounded figure"
> 2. full, varied, and satisfying, "a well-rounded life"
> 3. well planned and balanced, "a well-rounded programme"

**If this is the case, what would I expect to hear?**

I'd expect, and would personally use, the following,

> Your writing is well-rounded.

Meaning that your grasp of grammar, syntax, vocabulary, and writing style is good.

In this context you could say:

> Your writing should be better rounded.

But that would sound very odd to me and would take me a bit to work out its context. That might come from my background as a technical writer. In the technical writing world, specificity is important. Therefore, I would expect to hear:

> You need to improve your syntax and grammar, but your vocabulary is good.

*If what I have just explained doesn't reflect what you are trying to understand, please edit your post to provide more detail about the meaning of the sentences you provided.*

Comment: Thank you very much. Very complete and useful answer. I edited my question for a final clarification related to what you provided

Comment: Edited my question further. Would be great to know the usage nuances. Thank you.

Comment: All of them  don't make sense to you, or not one of them makes sense to you?